# Problems on Minecraft PS Vita version

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, ps-vita

I have 2 PlayStation Vitas each running its own copy of Minecraft.

When I connect them to each other in ad-hoc mode we get multi-player but only 1 of us can see the mobs. However, we can see each other and build.

Also, there is an issue where we both have the same player name tag. Any help in explaining why or a possible resolution would be of great help.

Comment: well thanks anyway..
guess i'll have to try muddle through and fnd an answer
i'll post here if i do.
thanks again,
Tiny.